# SQL Server - Updating missing history

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with a ~30,000 record contract history table, represented here by `#CONTR`.  The Original Contract Line Number `OCL` column in the table is incomplete.  I need to update `OCL` where appropriate (see notes on `INSERT` statements).

OCL should be NULL for new Contract Lines.  Some correct examples:  `CONT`&`CL` =  1415&1, 1415&2, 1415&3, 1415&16, 2025&1, 2025&2, and 2025&13). No examples needing update.

Upon the first renewal of the Contract Line OCL should be equal to PCL.  Some correct examples:  `CONT`&`CL` =  1415&20 and 2015&16.  Some examples needing update:  `CONT`&`CL` =  1415&4, 1415&5, 1415&6, 2025&3, and 2025&4.

Upon the second, and subsequent, renewals, OCL should always be equal to the Contract Line from which it originated.  Some correct examples:  `CONT`&`CL` =  1415&10, 1415&11, 2015&9, and 2025&10.  Some examples needing update:  `CONT`&`CL` =  1415&6, 1415&7, 2025&5, and 2025&6

```
CREATE TABLE #CONTR
(
CONT    INT ,   --  PK Col1, Contract Number
OCL     INT ,   --  Original Contract Line Number
CL      INT ,   --  PK Col2, Contract Line Number
PCL     INT ,   --  Previous Contract Line Number
NCL     INT     --  Next Contract Line Number
)

INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,NULL,1,0,4)
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,NULL,2,0,5) 
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,NULL,3,0,6) 
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,NULL,4,1,7)     -- OCL needs to be updated to 1
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,NULL,5,2,8)     -- OCL needs to be updated to 2
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,NULL,6,3,9)     -- OCL needs to be updated to 3
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,NULL,7,4,10)    -- OCL needs to be updated to 1
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,NULL,8,5,11)    -- OCL needs to be updated to 2
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,NULL,9,6,12)    -- OCL needs to be updated to 3
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,1,10,7,13)  
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,2,11,8,14)  
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,3,12,9,15)  
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,1,13,10,17) 
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,2,14,11,18) 
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,3,15,12,19) 
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,NULL,16,0,20)   
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,1,17,13,21) 
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,2,18,14,22) 
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,3,19,15,23) 
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (1415,16,20,16,24)    
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,NULL,1,0,5) 
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,NULL,2,0,6) 
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,NULL,3,1,5)     -- OCL needs to be updated to 1
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,NULL,4,2,6)     -- OCL needs to be updated to 2
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,NULL,5,3,7)     -- OCL needs to be updated to 1
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,NULL,6,4,8)     -- OCL needs to be updated to 2
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,NULL,7,5,9)     -- OCL needs to be updated to 1
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,NULL,8,6,10)    -- OCL needs to be updated to 2
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,1,9,7,11)   
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,2,10,8,12)  
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,1,11,9,14)  
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,2,12,10,15) 
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,NULL,13,0,16)   
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,1,14,11,17) 
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,2,15,12,18) 
INSERT INTO #CONTR VALUES (2025,13,16,13,19)
```

I tried the `UPDATE`s below, but they do not correct all the instances of `OCL` being incorrectly NULL when the Contract Line Number is not new, and there may be cases in the real data that have a longer history of `OCL` being incorrectly NULL than we have in this sample with `CONT` = 2025.

```
UPDATE #CONTR
SET    OCL = C1.PCL
FROM #CONTR C1
     JOIN 
     (SELECT * FROM #CONTR WHERE PCL = 0) C2
     ON C1.CONT = C2.CONT
     AND C1.PCL = C2.CL
     WHERE C1.OCL IS NULL AND C1.PCL != 0

UPDATE #CONTR
SET    OCL = C2.PCL
FROM #CONTR C1
     JOIN 
     (SELECT * FROM #CONTR WHERE PCL != 0 AND PCL = OCL) C2
     ON C1.CONT = C2.CONT
     AND C1.PCL = C2.CL
     WHERE C1.OCL IS NULL AND C1.PCL != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 UPDATE
    c1
SET
    c1.OCL=c2.PCL
FROM
    #CONTR c1
INNER JOIN
    #CONTR c2
ON
    c1.CONT = c2.CONT where C1.OCL IS NULL AND C1.PCL != 0 and c2.PCL=0
```

Comment: Thanks, user3540365.  I'm getting the following messages with that:`Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "C1.OCL" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "C1.PCL" could not be bound.

Comment: i just run the query and it was fine. @jejo